# Logo doesn't appear in the header

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a website for my friend, but I ran into an issue. A very irritating one. I have a header (a div with the id of header) and an ul inside of it. I added my `<img src="filename.extension" id="logo">` into my header div, but it appears underneath the actual header. I did float: right; thinking it would appear inside the header but it doesn't. And I added a border of 1px around the ul to see if it took up to much space, but there were enough space left for the logo to fit.

Here's my code:
(HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="headercon">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img id="logo" src="vglogo.png">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(CSS):

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header>#headercon>ul {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#headercon {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#logo {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headercon">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <img id="logo" src="vglogo.png"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In which Folder is your logo?

Comment: My logo is displaying but not as I expected it to

Comment: But it is in the same folder as everything else

Comment: Can you create one fiddle or something similar? Are you getting any error message in console logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may expected it like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}

#header>ul>li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#header>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.logo {
  float: right!important;
  right:40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.logo img{
  height:50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
        <li class="logo"><img id="logo" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579d30036a49638cd66ee855/57a69cadb3db2b8908f27da1/57a69d90e6f2e1f140d7bcfa/1470542795812/Intel_logo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Could you possibly explain what you changed and what I did wrong? Would be really helpful

Comment: The img in the last li, removed `div.#headercon, display: flex,
  line-height: 10px;`, added some css `.logo {
  float: right!important;
  right:40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.logo img{
  height:50px
}, #header>ul>li>a`